# $ instance Wordpress vs Jquery

Tags: wordpress

I have a question about the problem with wordpress and jquery: I have noticed that wordpress have more problem with the introduction of jquery insert in the custom template:

in one words,when i put the code inside header like  and i write an deblug function like 
    $(document).ready(function() { alert("ciao") });

he don't works and firefox debug told me "$ is not a function".

If i put the code inside footer like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    alert("ciao");

});


</script>
```

My sospiceus is that wordpress has more js library inside it..but if i write

```
   (function($) {

 $ Works! You can test it with next line if you like
 console.log($);

   })( jQuery );
```

$ accept it(in theory)..why all that?

Answer (score 1):

first of all, `$()` is just an alias to the  `jQuery()` function. the `$` is just a shorthand name so you would not write `jQuery` each time you use jQuery.

now i have seen a lot of times people complain about wordpress "hijacking" jQuery. what happens is that instead of `$` as jQuery, it's being used as something else, thus the error that `$ is not a function` - but we still have the longhand `jQuery()` function to the rescue.

but people tend to use the `$` because it's shorter, but how do we do this when `$` is "hijacked"? it's closures to the rescue also:

```
//others "$" for another library out here

(function($){
    //"jQuery" as "$" safely in here
}(jQuery));

//others "$" for another library out here
```

what the code does above is create a function that accepts a parameter which we name `$`, and execute it immediately, passing `jQuery` as the parameter. it roughly equivalent to this but without the name of the function:

```
function no_name($){
    //"jQuery" as "$" safely in here
}
no_name(jQuery);
```

so inside the function, `$` is a local variable. using `$` inside it pertains to the passed variable during the call, which is `jQuery` and not the global hijacked `$`.